# Print hostname into tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Hi I am trying to print out the results of this script into the gui window.

```
import socket   
hostname=socket.gethostname()   
IPAddr=socket.gethostbyname(hostname)   
print("Your Computer Name is:"+hostname)   
print("Your Computer IP Address is:"+IPAddr)
```

Here is the code it needs to work with. Thanks!

```
# Import module
from tkinter import *


# Create object
root = Tk()


# Adjust size
root.geometry("200x80")

# Create transparent window
root.attributes('-alpha', 0.5)

# Execute tkinter
root.mainloop()
```

I tried editing it manually from comments from google. but couldn't get it working.

Comment: You cannot "print to" a GUI. All this does is open a blank window... What have you tried to do to add a `Text` widget? And set its textual value?

Comment: yes I tried pasting print string but nothing showed up.

Comment: How would I get the ip address info to show up in the window?

Comment: Look up how to create `Text` widgets and set their value in tkinter.

Comment: If you add `print()` lines to Tkinter script, it still is printed to a terminal. You need to use a Text item - https://www.pythontutorial.net/tkinter/tkinter-text/

Comment: Label will also work - https://www.pythontutorial.net/tkinter/tkinter-label/ or Entry if you don't want a large Textarea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use wildcard `from tkinter import *`

- Added `Text` widget.
- Used f-string format.

Snippet:

```
import socket
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
hostname = socket.gethostname()   
IPAddr = socket.gethostbyname(hostname)   
print("Your Computer Name is:"+hostname)   
print("Your Computer IP Address is:"+IPAddr)

root.geometry("200x80")

txt_socket = tk.Text(root)
txt_socket.insert(tk.END, f"Your Computer Name is: {hostname}\n")
txt_socket.insert(tk.END, f"Your Computer IP Address is: {IPAddr}\n")

txt_socket.pack()

# Execute tkinter
root.mainloop()
```